Use python pattern matching on dict[str, str] instead of dict[Unknown, Unknown]
I find pattern matching on Sequence[str] quite beautiful.
I can also create a matching on dict. But is there an elegant way to perform pattern matching directly on dict[str, str] ?
Below is the current code
match config.get_main_option("mergetree_settings"):
    case str() as s:
        match json.loads(s):
            case [str()] as settings: # settings: Sequence[str]
                print(settings)
            case dict() as settings: # settings: dict[Unknown, Unknown]
                print(settings)
            case _:
                pass



This would essentially require the matcher to do all(isinstance(key, str) and isinstance(val, str) for key, val in value.items()).
